# Prevent from views re-rendering

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to tell Ember not to re-render views?

A simple use case:

I have a client list that is populated dynamically.
Clicking on a client in the list goes to the client details page.
When I click "back" I want to be exactly at the same position in the clients list.

Normally, Ember re-renders the view (as I transition into another state) and I my previous position gets lost.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: add a sidepanel with the list of clients with space beside the panel to have an outlet, when a client is clicked, the outlet has the details, this way ur position is preserved...getting me ?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you can't stop the re-render with ember if you are navigating to a different part of the application. If it is no longer visible, the items have been popped off the DOM and no longer exist.

I've solved this problem in my own applications by using jQuery to get the scroll position of the page or object. [jQuery Scroll Top](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). What I did was I had a place on the model that stored the scroll position. Then on the view I had a something like

```
didInsertElement: function() {

    //Restore previous scroll position
    $('#item').scrollTop( this.get('model.scrollPosition') ); /* or on older ember builds `this.getPath('model.scrollPosition')` */

    //Update the model with new scroll position when user scrolls
    var _self = this;
    $('#item').scroll(function(e){
         _self.get('model').set('scrollPosition', $(this).scrollTop());
    });

}
```

The key takeaway here is that the views **must** re-render. There is no stopping that. Your job as a developer is to save whatever state you need for the view (scroll position, element with focus, etc) in a way that it can be restored. Ember gives you the tools to do it.